# Issue deploying grails 3.1.7 in apache tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails

My app runs fine in dev mode, and I have done several test with it running n dev mode.I believe I have read enough on deploying grails application as a war in a servlet container.

I have changed the scope for embedded tomcat to provided

```
provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
```

I have generated the war using the command grails war and its output is below:

```
grails war
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:findMainClass
:assetCompile UP-TO-DATE
:buildProperties
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:compileWebappGroovyPages UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovyPages UP-TO-DATE
:war
:bootRepackage
:assemble

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

| Built application to build/libs using environment: production
```

When I deploy on both tomcat7 then on tomcat8.0.33 which is the version of the embedded one it still gives me this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry()Lorg/bson/codecs/configuration/CodecRegistry
```

full stack is available in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/wHKBwVGJ) .

But interestingly when I run it with the command below, on the same box where the tomcat is installed, it runs fine:

```
 java -Dgrails.env=prod -Dserver.port=9090 -jar my-grails-app-0.1.war
```

I am really keen in having this done with tomcat.I am not sure if I have missed any steps. Can anyone shed some lights on this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are using old driver `mongo-java-driver-2.13.3` which doesnt have
method `com.mongodb.MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry()`. This method was introduced in 3.0([link](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.2/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html#getDefaultCodecRegistry--)) so upgrading your driver should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What bothers me is that it works fine when I run the app as jar. That should be using the very old mongo-java-driver-2.13.3 still. Even in dev mode, it runs fine. that java-driver comes from `org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.8.1.RELEASE` and any attempt of using latest 1.9*.RELEASE version had failed at build time

Comment: Why are you using `spring-data-mongodb`? There is Grails plugin for that: `org.grails.plugins:mongodb`. And about that working jar, not working war: I honestly don't know, maybe there is used different strategy to create datasource on exploding war, maybe something else. Too much lines of code to look on. Sometimes its like this https://teacherlearnstocode.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/a6pswtfcuai7n-5.jpg

Comment: I'm curious how you figured out which mongo-java-driver he was using. I am using org.grails.plugins:mongodb:5.0.1 and grails 3.1.10 and i'm seein gthis same error message ONLY when i deploy a war to a tomcat.  Works great on run-app